# mysql_fetch problems... I'm getting crazy

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sorry, probably somewhere there will be the answer to my question, but it's hours I'm looking for trying to resolve this problem:
Here is the code:

```
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("****","****","***");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

        mysql_select_db("******", $con);

    $query = "SELECT id FROM fq_questions";
    $rowcnt = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query));      
    echo "Tot scenes: ".$rowcnt;
    $id = rand (1,$rowcnt);
    echo "<br>Id rand: ".$id."<br>";    
flush();
    $newquery = "SELECT question FROM fq_questions WHERE id=".$id;
    $result = mysql_query($newquery);
    if (!$result) {
        $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
        $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $newquery;
        die($message);
    }

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $row['question'];

    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

The problem is that there is no output. I've tried everything, seems to be a problem into the query, but *there is* a result, it's not false, but even if it exists, nothing is outputted.
The code works till

```
    echo "<br>Id rand: ".$id."<br>";
```

then it shows nothing.
It's a dummy problem, i'm getting crazy just because of it.

Uh, was forgetting... The website where I've got the problem: http://www.freelabs.it/filmquiz/game.php

Comment: what is the output of the previous `echo` (i.e. what is $rowcnt)

Comment: The `mysql_` extensions are deprecated in PHP 5.5 and you should use PDO or MySQLi or something! Anyway, do you mean `Tot scenes: <some number>` shows up?

Comment: "desc" is a MySQL reserved word, you should just change that column name in your DB

Comment: I think it is because you did `mysql_fetch_row`. Did you mean `mysql_fetch_assoc`?

Comment: also, what happens if you put a call to `flush` right after you echo the random number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"desc" is a MySQL reserved word, you should just change that column name in your DB. Anyway, your method is not random at all, and it will fail as soon as you have a "hole" in your ids (when you delete one member).

Take a look at MySQL "ORDER BY RAND()"

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT description FROM fq_questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'm trying that way.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful, `desc` is a SQL keyword ! Your query may not compile because of that.

Comment: that's right. If you have a column, for some unforgivable reason, named "desc", then you need to enclose it in single-quotes

Comment: Nothing, it still shows nothing... added a flush() function before the new query and changed the column name...

Comment: Look at the others comments and answers, you probably did a confusion between fatch_row() and fetch_assoc(). Otherwise, you soud have a look on RAND() function to randomize your results.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'm trying that way.

Comment: You could consider accepting the answer that helped you most. @AlbertoZanatta

Answer (score 0):

You used `mysql_fetch_row()` which returns a numerical array. You then try to access the array  slot named 'desc'.
It doesn't exist. (My guess is that that produces a supressed error, preventing any output from showing up, or a supressed warning, preventing any output after that line from showing up.)
Try changing `mysql_fetch_row()` to `mysql_fetch_assoc()` (still DEPRECATED!) and that should be solved.

Sources: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php
And: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php